# Replacing NAs with values from same column given conditional on match of third column

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, tidyr

I need to replace the NA's of each row with non NA's values of different row for a given column.

In the var2 column I don't have unique values between names. i.e. there could be one var2 value which is shared across id.

```
name<- rep(c("yygy","gryh","glqy","abye"),4)
var2<- c(101,102,102,104,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
data.frame(name,var2)



     name var2
  1  yygy  101
  2  gryh  102
  3  glqy  102
  4  abye  104
  5  yygy   NA
  6  gryh   NA
  7  glqy   NA
  8  abye   NA
  9  yygy   NA
  10 gryh   NA
  11 glqy   NA
  12 abye   NA
  13 yygy   NA
  14 gryh   NA
  15 glqy   NA
  16 abye   NA
```

Essentially in the above example I would want to repeat the var2 value across all matching name values i.e. for yygy there would be four rows each with 101.

I was thinking a join function from dplyr would work but couldn't quite get there. Of course this could be done with a loop but ideally looking for either a tidyr/dplyr method or apply perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `tidyr::fill()`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  fill(var2)

# A tibble: 16 x 2
# Groups:   name [4]
name  var2
<fctr> <dbl>
1   abye   104
2   abye   104
3   abye   104
4   abye   104
5   glqy   102
6   glqy   102
7   glqy   102
8   glqy   102
9   gryh   102
10   gryh   102
11   gryh   102
12   gryh   102
13   yygy   101
14   yygy   101
15   yygy   101
16   yygy   101
```

Comment: Thanks.I was looking at help file and it states that it fills the rows with previous entry. So I'm guessing that the reason it works is that group_by sorts the df out by name....what if there were to be a name with a value missing all toghether? wouldn't this throw it off as it would pick up value from previous name?

Comment: If name 'glqy' was originally `NA` in var2 and not '102', then all values  would remain `NA` after using the `fill()` command. It would not use the value from name 'abye'.

Comment: Ah ok sweet. Thanks!. Is there a way to keep order or to revert to original order?

Comment: I don't think there's a simple/clean way, but you could do something like `df %>% 
  mutate(ord = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  fill(var2) %>% 
  arrange(ord) %>% 
  select(-ord)` or use `arrange` if there is another field like date that might be sequential.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `replace` after grouping by 'name'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(name)  %>% 
  mutate(var2 = replace(var2, is.na(var2), var2[!is.na(var2)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R

```
df2 <- merge(df1[1],subset(df1,!is.na(var2),all.x=TRUE))

#    name var2
# 1  abye  104
# 2  abye  104
# 3  abye  104
# 4  abye  104
# 5  glqy  102
# 6  glqy  102
# 7  glqy  102
# 8  glqy  102
# 9  gryh  102
# 10 gryh  102
# 11 gryh  102
# 12 gryh  102
# 13 yygy  101
# 14 yygy  101
# 15 yygy  101
# 16 yygy  101
```

or to keep order:

```
df2 <- merge(df1[1],subset(df1,!is.na(var2),all.x=TRUE)
             )[rank(df1$name,ties.method="first"),]
rownames(df2) <- NULL

#    name var2
# 1  yygy  101
# 2  gryh  102
# 3  glqy  102
# 4  abye  104
# 5  yygy  101
# 6  gryh  102
# 7  glqy  102
# 8  abye  104
# 9  yygy  101
# 10 gryh  102
# 11 glqy  102
# 12 abye  104
# 13 yygy  101
# 14 gryh  102
# 15 glqy  102
# 16 abye  104
```

**data**

```
name<- rep(c("yygy","gryh","glqy","abye"),4)
var2<- c(101,102,102,104,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
df1 <- data.frame(name,var2)
```

Comment: I think this would be ok if there weren't more than 2 data columns in my dataframe but there are and it seems to mess up because of it (sorry I should have said). Thanks for input thought. Sbha's answer seems to have done the job.

Comment: if you use `df1[-2]` instead of `df1[1]` and `subset(df1[c("name","var2")],!is.na(var2))` it should work (using the correct index of the column instead of 2)

Comment: sbha's solution is the best way if you use `dplyr`, I would have used it (and I had started to type it :)), I'm just providing the base alternative. It doesn't preserve the order though.